# docker-compose failed after deleting docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, docker-image

`ERROR: build path /Users/client/lib/funnel_chart either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL.`

I got this error when I force deleted a directory when there is a merge conflict. And when I try to do the `docker-compose down` or even `docker-compose down --rmi all` it would still shows up this error. Same thing happens for `docker-compose rm -all` and `docker-compose-dev.yml up`.

Comment: Yes, after creating the directory, it can be shut down normally. Thanks.

Comment: Now that I know that worked, I'll turn that into an answer (people never read comments...)

Answer (score 6):

You have a `build` parameter in your docker-compose.yml.

Even if you didn't ask docker-compose to do a build, it still checks that the referred-to build directories (if any) defined in the file are there. If any of them are missing, it throws its hands in the air and gives up.

You can fix this by either removing that `build` parameter from docker-compose.yml, or recreating the directory. Even if the directory is empty, it should be sufficient for you to run `docker-compose down` and turn things off.